# When is a Lipschitz homeomorphism of metric spaces bi-Lipschitz?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $(X,d_X)$ and $(Y, d_Y)$ be metric spaces, and let $f: X \to Y$ be a Lipschitz map which is a homeomorphism of the underlying topological spaces. Are there conditions which assure that $f$ is indeed bi-Lipschitz (that is, $f^{-1}$ is Lipschitz)? For example, is it true when $X$ and $Y$ are compact? [EDIT: compactness is not sufficient, for example consider the function $x \mapsto x^3$ defined on $[-1,1]$.]

My question is possibly related to [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/280401/equivalence-of-intrinsic-and-extrinsic-metrics-of-embedded-manifolds) about the equivalence of the geodesic distance and the induced euclidean distance on a riemannian manifold embedded in $\mathbb R^m$.

Comment: In the context if smooth compact Riemannian (or Finsler) manifolds a diffeomorphism will suffice. In the case if arbitrary metric spaces, a map which is bilipschitz on all r-balls (r is large) and a quasi-isometry (with constants smaller than r) would suffice too.

Comment: Do you have any reference for the assertion about compact Riemannian manifolds?

Comment: I do not have a reference, but this is an immediate application of two things: (1) That the exponential map is a local diffeomorphism, (2) the mean value theorem in $R^n$ which implies that a diffeomorphism of $R^n$ with norm of the derivative bounded above and Jacobian bounded away from 0 is a bilipschitz map. If you like, I can write a detailed argument as an answer.

Comment: Oh, yes, it would be helpful! Perhaps it could answer also the other question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/280401/equivalence-of-intrinsic-and-extrinsic-metrics-of-embedded-manifolds

Comment: Yes, it does answer the other question too. I will write a detailed answer when I have time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Lemma. Suppose that $X, Y$ are smooth compact Riemannian $n$-manifolds, $f: X\to Y$ is a diffeomorphism. Then $f$ is bilipschitz with respect to the Riemannian distance functions.

Proof. It clearly suffices to show that $f$ is Lipschitz (considering the inverse we will get the bilipschitz property).

Edit: I do not know why did I write such a complicated proof at first. Here is a much shorter one. Let $UX$ denote the unit tangent bundle of $X$. Then the map $df: UX\to TY$ is continuous, since we assumed that $f$ is smooth. Therefore, since the Riemannian metric on $Y$ is smooth, the function $\phi(u)=|df(u)|$, $u\in UX$ is continuous too. Let $C$ denote its maximum (which exists since $UX$ is compact). Therefore, for every unit speed piecewise-smooth path $c: [a,b]\to X$ the length of its image
$$
L(f\circ c)= \int_{a}^b |(f\circ c)'|dt\le C \int_a^b |c'(t)|dt= C L(c),
$$
where $L(c)$ is the length of the path in $X$ and $L(f\circ c)$ is the length in $Y$. Therefore, $f$ increases length of paths at most by the factor $C$. Since the distance functions on $X$ and $Y$ are defined by minimizing lengths of paths between points, it follows that
$$
d_Y(f(p), f(q))\le C d_X(p, q), p, q\in X.
$$
Hence, $f$ is $C$-Lipschitz. qed