# Ratio of metric on manifold $\Omega$ and induced metric on imbedded manifold $M$

Tags: differential-geometry, metric-spaces, manifolds, riemannian-geometry, smooth-manifolds

The author writes:

> Often one has an $n$-dimensional manifold $M$ imbedded in an $m$-dimensional
> Riemannian manifold $\Omega$, perhaps $\Omega = \mathbb{R}^m$. Give $M$ the induced Riemannian metric. Then $M$ has two distance functions, $d_M(p,q)$, from minimizing
> the lengths of curves in $M$ from $p$ to $q$, and $d_{\Omega}(p, q)$, from considering
> all curves in $\Omega$ from $p$ to $q$.

He then claims that

> $$d_M(p, q) = \phi(p, q)d_{\Omega}(p, q),$$
> with $\phi : M \times M \to (0, \infty)$ continuous and $\phi(p, p) = 1$.

I wonder how to prove this assertion. I can prove it in the case where $M = \gamma([a, b])$ is a $C^1$ smooth curve and $\Omega = \mathbb{R}^m$ because in this case there is a unit speed parameterization for $M$ and then the limit $\lim_{(p, q) \to (p_0, p_0)}\frac{d_M(p, q)}{d_{\Omega}(p, q)}$ is $1$.

Comment: See my answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/280401/equivalence-of-intrinsic-and-extrinsic-metrics-of-embedded-manifolds/566430#566430).

Comment: @MoisheKohan I was able to adapt my argument for the $n = 1$, $\Omega = \mathbb{R}^m$ case to the $n$ arbitrary, $\Omega = \mathbb{R}^m$ case. This is sufficient for my purposes. It seems that the case where $\Omega$ is arbitrary is a bit more difficult since the derivative of a coordinate chart is not defined in the usual calculus sense.